# socket programming in mingw

Tags: c++, sockets, mingw

I Write a server/client C++ code and test in Visual Studio, and it was OK, 
But i want to convert to CodeBlocks MinGW(Gnu CC Compiler) and it return some error, like:

**warning:** ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

**error:** 'getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope|

**error:** 'freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope|

**My Server Code :**

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;


    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;


    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    closesocket(ListenSocket);


    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);


            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);


    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**My Client Code :**

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;


    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }


    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;


    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {


        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }


        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %i\n", iResult);


    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );


    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone Help me?

Comment: it works fine for me, mingw64-gcc 4.6.3

Answer (score 6):

Insert `#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x501` at the top of your files (before the includes).

This is the cause of your problem (**`ws2tcpip.h`**):

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
void WSAAPI freeaddrinfo (struct addrinfo*);
int WSAAPI getaddrinfo (const char*,const char*,const struct addrinfo*,
                struct addrinfo**);
int WSAAPI getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr*,socklen_t,char*,DWORD,
               char*,DWORD,int);
#else
/* FIXME: Need WS protocol-independent API helpers.  */
#endif
```

The prototypes of those functions are only available if `_WIN32_WINNT` is defined to *0x051* or higher.

Comment: Ok, please set this value using a compiler flag instead, does it work then? Btw. what version of Windows are you using?