# CMAKE getaddrinfo error during make of libssh

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, libssh

I am using `CMAKE` with `minGW` to compile `libssh`.

But every time I get `getaddrInfo` error. I guess it's not able to link with `ws2_32.lib`.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: see its LIBSSH source code i am using .

Comment: possible duplicate of [socket programming in mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303583/socket-programming-in-mingw)