# Compile TCP IP Server with MSYS2 and C

Tags: c, tcpclient, msys2, tcpserver

I want to compile a TCP/IP Server using MSYS2 and C.
I have copied the code from here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/, saved it in a file tcpserver.c and tried to compile it with the command
gcc -o tcpserver tcpserver.c
However, I get the error message

```
gcc -o tcpserver tcpserver.c 
tcpserver.c:2:10: fatal error: netdb.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <netdb.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My question: Which packman package do I have to install (I use the MSYS2 shell normally)
So I am looking for the right package, that I can install with

```
pacman -S <name of the package>
```

or some other solution, that works of course.

Update:
I just launched the 32-bit-MSYS2 shell and run the same commmands to compile, and there it compiles fine and the tcp-ip-server can be launched.
But from the 64-bit-MSYS2 shell it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to use Windows headers and functions (winsock ones in particular), not posix/unix ones.

Comment: See [socket programming in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20303583/3422102) for a reasonable example. (avoid geeks-for-geeks like the plague, many examples are just ... wrong)

Comment: If you are building the program to run in the MSYS runtime environment itself (i.e. using the cygwin C libraries, not the native ucrt or msvcrt C libraries), then the necessary socket header files are installed by the `msys2-runtime-devel` package. For the native runtime environments (ucrt or msvcrt C libraries), you will need to use the native Windows socket libraries (Winsock2).